# Apply operators to two objects without 'dynamic'

Tags: c#, operators, interpreter

Context: I am writing an interpreter for a simple language, for users to have play around with and have fun. It will run as a mod to a game. The reason I can't use dynamic is because the game runs in Unity3d, which runs the version of Mono equivalent to .net 3.5 (which does not have dynamic).

Now for the question: I store values as objects. When evaluating expressions (say, adding), I have the problem of trying to do "object + object". How can I do this?

One solution is to do a massive switchblock on each object, checking it's type to see if it's a basic value type (int, long, double, etc), if so, casting to that type and adding. If it's not a basic value type, look for an op_Addition method in each type and if it exists, call it.

This can get to be a lot of code very quickly doing this for each operator. I'm wondering if there's a better, less copy-paste-filled way. (the optimal solution would be some .net library function that's `object Add(object, object)`, but that's being hopeful)

Comment: You: _I store values as objects._ Why? In a type-safe language like C#, normally you wouldn't do that. Has it to do with the nature of the interpreter you're writing?

Comment: The reason I store them as objects is because I don't know the value of the type at compile-time. I don't know if the user is going to type in "new Regex()" or "3", so I have no idea what type it is. The only way to store that is by an object.

Comment: What is `Regex`? If the user types `"new Regex()"`, will you search the `System.dll` assembly, choose the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, find the type, search for a constructor overload that matches, and then invoke the constructor? Because if you do something similar to that, it's not too difficult to check for a `+` overload. Maybe what you need is "compiler as a service"? Or are you writing your own compiler?

Comment: So what happens when someone adds double to decimal?

Comment: I'm not writing my own compiler, I'm writing my own interpreter. Also, there are no 'compilers as a service' for the language I am writing it for (TI-Basic, or rather, object-oriented TI-Basic). And yes, I am searching `System.dll`, finding the Regex class, and invoking the constructor - which is actually quite easy, it's possible to do in two or three lines of code. The question I'm asking is if I need to check both sides of each basic value type on every single operator, which ends up being around 6000 if statements. (because basic value types do not overload operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an interface for your objects defining the operations you need, then make sure all stored objects implement that interface (perhaps wrapping simple types).